# Table row highlighting problem

Tags: jquery

The requirement is when i click on a text field, a table has to display below the text field and when i move my mouse over the rows, the rows must be highlighted - what am I doing wrong in my code?

My HTML has 2 elements:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Name"><div id="line"></div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.datahighlight {
        background-color: #ffdc87 !important;
}
```

And the jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#name").click(function(){
        $("#line").html("<table><tbody><tr class='simplehighlight'><td>Text Row to be highlighted</td></tr></tbody></table>");

    });

    $('.simplehighlight').hover(function(){
            $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight');
        },function(){
            $(this).children().removeClass('datahighlight');
        });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the jQuery 'live' bindings. Try this:

```
$('.simplehighlight').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight');
}).live('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).children().removeClass('datahighlight');
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LsDGZ/

Comment: To be specific, `hover` does not work because the table does not exist when you are trying to apply the handler.  `live` binds handlers to the root of the DOM tree, and handles events as they bubble up the tree.

Comment: Works like a charm, i tried this earlier and it did not work - i realize now that .live() was introduced jquery 1.3 onwards and drupal was using the 1.2 version - i would be interested to know the pure JavaScript implementation